# kubernetes works only with sleep infinity args any other command doesn't work

Tags: linux, kubernetes, jvm

my application starts with a script startup.sh everytime container gets spawned. After 40 seconds, container gets killed automatically, and respawns with new container ID.
[image]

I tried livenessprobe, readyness probe and startupprobes with high period values but no luck.

I checked inside container one sleep 30 process runs by default.
[image]
Only solution that worked for me was adding sleep infinity with my startup.sh like args: ["./startup.sh; sleep infinity"] in deployment.yaml.

[image]

process inside container running normally and not getting killed after 40 seconds
[image]

Can someone suggest any other way or some reference from kubernetes why it worked.

Comment: Have you checked the reason for the container restart - exit code, logs, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your application doing? If it is an application that does not run infinitely (eg. a WebServer) it throws an exit code after it is done. If kubernetes recieves this exit code it will restart the container.

So again. If your application (shell script) finishes with an exit code it is totally normal it gets restarted by kubernetes.